# Stress relief of parakeets? Is vegetable glycerine safe for parakeets/ small birds?

Tags: medicines, birds, stress, budgerigar

I just brought home a baby parakeet. I know the typical recommendation for having a parakeet is either provide it with enough attention that it accepts you as it's flock or give it a buddy. My intention is to keep him as a lone parakeet, that attaches to me  vs another bird in its cage. I know this process may take some time for him to warm up to me but until he trusts me I know he will be a little stressed (he's a baby so he will adapt But he was caged with 8 other parakeets and is now alone).

I have read that rescue remedy flower essences for pets is "safe" for birds because it's base is vegetable glycerin instead of alcohol but it comes in a dropper bottle and I can't find info on how much to give him. I could see giving one or two drops in a larger parrots water being of little concern but I wonder about the dosage and safeness for a tiny bird like my budgie.

What's the dosage?
Does anyone know if vegetable glycerin could cause diarrhea? Or has anyone used this on birds before? If so, how much did you give? By mouth or in water dish? Does anyone have any other tips on what would be a good stress relieving supplement instead? I just want to make him as comfortable as possible, I'm much more used to larger birds, and know budgies have sensitive bodies and that stress can literally kill them.

Background, behavior and Environment Info: he's between 2-3 months old. His cage is placed in view of my cockatiel, but not within reach of each other. The room he's in has the most amount of activity so he's never in dead space. He's already stepping up onto my finger, and will hang onto my shirt, but doesn't hang out for more than 5minutes before getting wiggly, as of yet. He has plenty of toys and perches, and he has ample water and seed (the same kind he was on at the pet store until I've had him long enough to switch). A spray of millet is available. I cover him at night. He's strictly indoors. He didn't eat food for the first day except a little millet, but is eating now. It's day 3. He had what I'd assume was stress induced diarrhea for the first 24hrs, I assume stress because it went away after he started eating again. He was not hand fed or hand raised and has no ankle band. The store he came from does not allow customer interaction with them which is good for stress and contamination while there, but not so good for human socialization or hand recognition. He made little chirping sounds at the pet store but hasn't made a sound until tonight... After covering him it sounded like he was purring himself to sleep.

Active Ingredients: HPUS 5x dilution of Helianthemum, Hummularium, Clematis Vitalba, Impatiens glandulifera, Primus cerasifera, Ornithogalum umbellatum. Inactive Ingredients: 80%Glycerin 20%water. The active ingredients are the Latin names for the different flower essences.

Comment: we will need the exact ingredients of the rescue remedy - I actually have a bottle here - but best you post yours in case they're different. I've had a lot of experience with budgies - they're native here :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Awesome! Should I edit my question to include that, or just comment?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it reads: Active Ingredients: HPUS 5x dilution of Helianthemum, Hummularium, Clematis Vitalba, Impatiens glandulifera, Primus cerasifera, Ornithogalum umbellatum.  Inactive Ingredients: 80%Glycerin 20%water. The active ingredients are the Latin names for the different flower essences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not risk giving these drops to your budgie or any bird. Many of the flowers are safe - I cannot verify that they are all safe. However glycerin is something that should only be given to birds with the utmost care and really isn't necessary for their well being, but can easily make a bird ill or even be lethal.

Given budgies are such small birds, the propensity to overdose the bird with glycerin is even greater.

There is evidence that small amounts of glycerin may assist heat stressed chickens, but the level of glycerin that is beneficial can easily become a level that has an adverse affect on the birds health. There is a fine line. (1)

From [Cornell Lab of Ornithology Bird Note *Providing water for birds*](http://www.birds.cornell.edu/AllAboutBirds/notes/BirdNote09_ProvideWater.pdf)

> Ingesting large amounts of glycerin elevates the blood sugar level of
>   a bird, which can be harmful or even fatal

Any benefits would be outweighed by the potential side effects.

The better option may be to grow and provide access to the actual flowers for your bird, ensuring that you only use flowers that are safe for your bird.

Here is a list of [Bird-Safe Edible Flowers](https://www.petcha.com/bird-safe-edible-flowers/):

> African Tulip Tree (Spathodea campanulata)
>
> Apple blossum (Malus domestica)
>
> Bald Cypress (Taxodium distichum)
>
> Basil (Ocimum basilicum)
>
> Bee balm (Monarda)
>
> Borage blossoms (Borago officinalis)
>
> Bottlebrush (Callistemon spp.)
>
> Calendula (Pot Marigold) (Calendula officinalis)
>
> Carnations (Dianthus caryophyllus)
>
> Chamomile (Chamaemelum nobile)
>
> Chives (allium schoenoprasum)
>
> Coriander/cilantro (Coriandrum sativum)
>
> Daises
>
> Dandelion (Taraxacum)
>
> Daylily (Hemerocallis spp.)
>
> Dill  (Anethum graveolen)
>
> Elderberry (Sambucus spp.)
>
> Eucalyptus
>
> Fennel (Foeniculum vulgare)
>
> Gardenia (Gardenia jasminoides)
>
> Garlic  (Allium sativum L.)
>
> Gladiolus
>
> Grapefruit (Citrus x paradise)
>
> Hibiscus
>
> Honeysuckle (Lonicera)
>
> Impatiens
>
> Jarcaranda (Jacaranda mimosifolia)
>
> Kumquat (various Fortunella species)
>
> Lilac (Oleaceae Syringa)
>
> Lime (Citrus aurantifolia)
>
> Lemon (Citrus × lemon)
>
> Milk thistle (Silybum species)
>
> Melalecuca (Melaleuca quinquinervia)
>
> Nasturtiums
>
> Orchid tree (Bauhinia verigata)
>
> Congrats! You found the spring parrot!
>
> Okra (Abelmoschus esculentus)
>
> Orange (Citrus sinensis)
>
> Oregano (Origanum vulgare)
>
> Pansies (Viola tricolor)
>
> Passion flowers (Passifloraceae Passiflora)
>
> Petunia (Petunia spp.)
>
> Plum (Prunoideae Prunus)
>
> Pumpkin (Cucurbita pepo or Cucurbita mixta)
>
> Roses/Rose hips (Rosoideae Rosa)
>
> Rosemary (Rosmarinus officinalis)
>
> Runner Beans (Phaseolus coccineus)
>
> Sage (Salvia officinalis)
>
> Sunflowers (Helianthus annuus)
>
> Thyme (Lamiaceae Thyme)
>
> Zucchini (Cucurbita pepo.)
>
> Violets (Violaceae Viola)

1. Effects of the Addition of Pure Glycerin Supplementation in the Drinking Water on the Performance of Broilers Submitted to Heat Stress and Feed Restriction . 
   PO MoraesI, et al.
   http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/1806-9061-2015-0166

Comment: I have a dried greens mix with chamomile. Pic here.https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/122268553038_/Higgins-Sunburst-Leafy-Greens-and-Herbs-with-Chamomile.jpg. You think this would have the same effect or be just as beneficial? Growing my own would work for the future especially since I love my gardening, but being that he needs a  fix for his stress levels now (new environment) I'd have to stick with what I already have or can easily get. I grow my own chives, oregano, and daylilies, I'll try these too

Comment: also there's a difference between vegetable glycerin and pure glycerin. I see bottom statement refers to pure glycerin, does your first 3 stanzas also refer to pure? Found that "potency vitamin drops for birds" like ecotrition/8in, vetriscience, and oasis all have glycerin in their formulas. If used in moderation maybe follow guidelines for parakeets according to those instructions?? So strange it's hard to find feeding instructions on the flower essences

Comment: Note***Above^^ oasis no longer uses vegetable glycerin as an ingredient in their high potency vitamins. I never want to put any misguided info on here. Oops sorry

Comment: @ChristyB. now I'm confused as to what the ingredients are

Comment: No change, it's just when you go to the manufacturer website it specifies that it's inactive Ingredients are  vegetable glycerin and water.... And veggie is different than pure. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-glycerine-vegetable-glycerine&ved=0ahUKEwj55tvY0LfUAhUX7WMKHUFHC3kQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNHAAR1CenSXeDoS8dhGJLH-Lmih-A&sig2=iQByDU6tebmTJMZhZWtKoA

Comment: @ChristyB. from the link you've provided it states there's no difference between the source of the glycerin, pure glycerin is pure glycerin. It's impossible to know what the source of pure glycerin is, as it's available in many substances. Does that make sense?

Comment: rrrr I think so. I'm going to wait to see if any other answers are posted before accepting as correct... But I doubt much more info will be found. I've even contacted the manufacturer and they haven't responded back to me yet lol- I was told 1 drop per 1oz of drinking water for "parrots" with no specifications on parrot size. Maybe they'll respond too, either way I've received help.... I didn't realize some things I was already growing would help my little guy. Also, I know this sounds minor, but he seems to be ALOT more active since I've moved around the arrangement in his cage

Comment: @ChristyB. with budgies I'd recommend caution with taking a dosage for 'parrots' as they're so small. There's a possibility it will do no harm to your bird, personally, I wouldn't take the risk. Also no need to rush to accept - wait for the bounty to expire and see if others post.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm waiting for them to call me back, the rep said he only had the dosage for parrots in front of him but that they'd contact me about parakeets.... But Yes- what a broad dosage right? There's so many different sized parrots

Comment: @ChristyB. exactly